# Importing an xls file into SQL Server with a column with both alphanumerical and floats

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have to import quite often `.xls` files into SQL Server and sometimes (depending on the skills of the client) there is a field containing a code which can be an alphanumeric string or a number.

This causes some problems, I give you an example. Suppose that code in the first record is 0011 and abc1 in the second: obviously if I assign a numeric format with the wizard the second record is imported as a null value (the first in the example would be 11, which is not so good anyway), but if I import it as a char(4) I have the correct result for abc1, but 0011 becomes a null. Do you understand why? Is there a way to have the same codes of the input file?

Thank you

Comment: pull it all in as char into a staging table......

Comment: it's what i did, i have the issues i described

Comment: I believe that you shouldn't try to change it within ssms. You have to open excel and change the format of the column into char - text, something like that.

Comment: Try casting the Excel file into .csv and importing it as a flat file defining the column nvarchar(4)